# Finding UMVUE for $g(\theta)$ that satisfy $g(0)=0$ in discrete uniform $f(x\mid\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta} I_{1,...,\theta}(x)$

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, umvue

Let $x_1, \ldots x_n, \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim}f(x\mid \theta)=\frac{1}{\theta} I_{1,...,\theta}(x)$.

I know that $T=X_{(n)}$ is complete and sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and

$$f_T(t\mid\theta)= \left( \left(\frac{t}{\theta}\right)^n - \left(\frac{t-1}{\theta}\right)^n \right)I_{1,...,\theta}(t)$$

The problem is finding UMVUE estimator for arbitrary function of $\theta$, $g(\theta)$, that satisfy $g(0)=0$.

I need to find $h(t)$ such that satisfy

$$\sum_{t=1}^{\theta} h(t)\left(\left(\frac{t}{\theta}\right)^n-\left(\frac{t-1}{\theta}\right)^n \right)=g(\theta)$$

I saw it in *An Introduction to Probability and Statistics, Rohatgi, V.K. and Ehsanes Saleh*.

$\\$

**Update**: I get an answer, is it rigor?

$\\$

I followed this step, is it correct?

$\sum_{t=1}^{\theta} h(t)\left(\left(\frac{t}{\theta}\right)^n-\left(\frac{t-1}{\theta}\right)^n \right)=g(\theta)$

so

$g(\theta) \theta^n=\sum_{t=1}^{\theta} h(t)\left((t)^n-(t-1)^n \right) $

in hence

$g(\theta+1) (\theta+1)^n -g(\theta) \theta^n =\sum_{t=1}^{\theta+1} h(t)\left((t)^n-(t-1)^n \right)-\sum_{t=1}^{\theta} h(t)\left((t)^n-(t-1)^n \right)$

so

$g(\theta+1) (\theta+1)^n -g(\theta) \theta^n=  h(\theta+1)\left((\theta+1)^n-(\theta+1-1)^n \right)=
h(\theta+1)\left((\theta+1)^n-(\theta)^n \right)$

so

$h(\theta+1)=\frac{g(\theta+1) (\theta+1)^n -g(\theta) \theta^n}{\left((\theta+1)^n-(\theta)^n \right)}$

so

$h(\theta)=\frac{g(\theta) (\theta)^n -g(\theta-1) (\theta-1)^n}{\left((\theta)^n-(\theta-1)^n \right)}$

finally

$h(t)=\frac{g(t) (t)^n -g(t-1) (t-1)^n}{\left((t)^n-(t-1)^n \right)}$

It seem correct , is it?

Comment: For $t\ge 1$, your final answer is correct.